# C# Export function dll

Tags: c#, unmanaged, dllexport

I use the Unmanaged-Exports package from Robert Giesecke, which can be found at (https://sites.google.com/site/robertgiesecke/Home/uploads/unmanagedexports).

I'd like to export a function but somehow it doesn't work. The functions won't be exported.

My approach:

Code:

```
[DllExport("test", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static string test()
    {
        return "Hello World, this is the DLL";
    }
```

Screenshot of my IDA results:
[image: Valid XHTML]

As you can see they're empty because no function was exported.

Comment: It's work now.
Solution: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37675/Simple-Method-of-DLL-Export-without-C-CLI

Comment: If that solved your issue, you might want to post that as a answer instead of as a comment. With a small description of what exactly on that page helped you to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37675/Simple-Method-of-DLL-Export-without-C-CLI

Put the "DllExporter.exe" in your project folder.

German article: http://www.sotzny.de/2011/11/10/dllexport-net-ohne-ccli/